# How to Get Result on from JPA Custom @Query in Spring boot to DTO

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

i want to get result from this query to DTO without use Tuple.

@Repository
public interface CustomMapRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
@Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "select  i.id as  permissionId, p.id as projectId,p.name as projectName,i.user_id as userId,\n" +
        "case " +
        "when  i.scopes is not null then i.scopes\n" +
        "when i.scopes is null   then \"[{'edit':false},{'create':false},{'update':flase},{'delete':false},{'view':false}]\" end as scopes \n" +
        "from   internal_permission i  \n" +
        "right join project p\n" +
        "on i.project_id=p.id\n" +
        "where \n" +
        "(user_id=:userId or user_id is null )and \n" +
        "p.space_id=:spaceId )")
List<CustomMapDTO> findBySpaceIdAndUserId(@Param("spaceId") Long spaceId, @Param("userId") String userId);
```

}

```
the DTO Class
```

public class CustomMapDTO implements Serializable {

```
private  String permissionId;
private  Long projectId;
private  String projectName;
private  String userId;
private  String  scopes;
```

//..getters and setters
}

Comment: Why do you have a `name` parameter (that should link to a result mapping). Remove it. Also please explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you create a nativeQuery? Please read the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Ok I will remove it , do u have any way to solve this issue to get result from Query

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<CustomMapDTO> res= ((Session)this.em.getDelegate()).createSQLQuery(
        "\n select p.id as projectId,p.name as projectName, i.id as permissionId,i.user_id as userId,\n" +
            "case\n" +
            "  when  i.scopes is not null then i.scopes\n" +
            "  when i.scopes  is null   then \"[{'edit':false},{'create':false},{'update':flase},{'delete':false},{'view':false}]\" end as scopes \n" +
            "from internal_permission i right join project p \n" +
            "on i.project_id=p.id \n" +
        "where \n" +
        "((user_id=:userId or user_id is null ) " +
        " and \n" +
        "(p.space_id=:spaceId))")
        .addScalar("projectId", LongType.INSTANCE)
        .addScalar("projectName", StringType.INSTANCE)
        .addScalar("permissionId", LongType.INSTANCE)
        .addScalar("userId", StringType.INSTANCE)
        .addScalar("scopes", StringType.INSTANCE)
        .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer( CustomMapDTO.class))
        .setParameter("spaceId",spaceId)
        .setParameter("userId",userId)
        .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
        .getResultList();
```